# Calculating Mean Values for raster stack in R

Tags: r, mean, r-raster

I have a raster stack of 32 NPP files and want to calculate the mean. I always get NA as an answer.(Same for my NDVI files).

This is my code:

````
NPP.all.mean = rep(0, times = 32)
for(i in 1:32){
      NPP.all.mean[i] = mean(NPP_corrected[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
}
NPP

.mean = mean(ndvi.all.mean)   
    ```
    This is my desired plot with the mean of the mean and the single year values: 
    
    plot(dates$Date, ndvi.all.mean, type = 'l', col = 'darkgreen', lwd = 2, ylim = c(0, 1), xaxt = 'n',
         xlab = 'Datum', ylab = 'NDVI / NPP'')
    axis(side = 1, dates$Date, format(dates$Date, '%m-%Y'))
    abline(v = dates$Date, col = 'gray', lty = 'dotted')
    abline(h = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1), col = 'gray', lty = 'dotted')
    lines(dates$Datum, npp.all.mean, col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
    abline(h = ndvi.mean, col = 'green', lwd = 2)
    abline(h = npp.mean, col = 'cyan', lwd = 2)
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use `terra` package for this like

```
library(terra)

#stack rasters
Stack <- rast(files)

#Calculate mean of all the rasters using terra
global(Stack, "mean", na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear *which* mean you want. Do you want the *global* mean (one value for each layer) or the *local* mean (one value for each cell).

With "terra" and these example data

```
library(terra)
npp <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
```

The global mean is computed like this

```
global(npp, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#          mean
#red   182.2855
#green 185.3509
#blue  192.8046
```

And the local mean is computed like this:

```
mean(npp, na.rm=TRUE)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        : mean 
#min value   :    0 
#max value   :  255
```

Comment: I get a raster layer as a result, which is great but i need the single year mean values for my further analysis.... I would like to plot the mean values of NPP and NDVi over 10 years in one plot. I added the code to my question.